Portaudio and Opus cant work with webview, Why?
I've been working on a voice chat software recently and I made the server the client code and everything as a CLI, using portaudio and opus for recording and compressing audio.
But when I decided to remake it as a webview software, The project doesnt get compiled.
Note that webview test code works fine on it's own.
And the software with portaudio and opus works fine without the webview.
Here's what i write to compile it:

$env:CGO_CFLAGS="-IC:\msys64\mingw64\include\opus"
go build .

But when I include them all together, I get this large error message when compiling:
# logger
C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running g++ failed: exit status 1
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_util.c.obj):(.text+0xda): undefined reference to 
 reference to `__imp_waveInGetErrorTextW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0xe0c): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutPrepareHeader'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0xe8c): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInUnprepareHeader'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0xf0a): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutUnprepareHeader'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x1066): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInGetErrorTextW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x16fc): undefined reference to -w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x1dc9): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInReset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x1dd0): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInGetErrorTextW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x2720): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutGetPosition'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x2bd7): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInClose'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x2bfc): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInGetErrorTextW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x2c6d): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutClose'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x2c92): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutGetErrorTextW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x2fa5): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutOpen'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x2ff1): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutOpen'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x3049): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutGetErrorTextW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x3112): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInOpen'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x315a): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInOpen'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x31a2): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInGetErrorTextW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x4caa): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInMessage'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x4cdd): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutMessage'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x4d16): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInGetNumDevs'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x4d2b): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutGetNumDevs'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x4ee2): undefined reference to `__imp_waveInGetDevCapsW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wmme.c.obj):(.text+0x51da): undefined reference to `__imp_waveOutGetNumDevs'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wasapi.c.obj):(.text+0x3ee1): undefined reference to `__imp_timeBeginPeriod'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw3
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wasapi.c.obj):(.text+0x46d2): undefined reference to `__imp_timeGetTime'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x23b6): undefined reference to `__imp_timeEndPeriod'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x2502): undefined reference to `__imp_timeBeginPeriod'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x2656): undefined reference to `__imp_timeGetTime'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x5f13): undefined reference to `__imp_SetupDiGetClassDevsW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x5f27): undefined reference to `__imp_SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceAlias'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x5fb3): undefined reference to `__imp_SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x6112): undefined reference to `__imp_SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceAlias'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x6194): undefined reference to `__imp_SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetailW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x61fe): undefined reference to `__imp_SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x6411): undefined reference to `__imp_SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x643a): undefined reference to `__imp_SetupDiOpenDeviceInterfaceRegKey'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libportaudio.a(pa_win_wdmks.c.obj):(.text+0x6499): undefined reference to `__imp_SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList'
./../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_buffer'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: : C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0xf89): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_reset_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0xf94): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_pagein'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: usfile.o):(.text+0x10f3): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_packetout'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x115b): undefined reference to `ogg_page_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x1168): undefined reference to `ogg_page_bos'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x117c): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_pagein'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x118c): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_pagein'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x12e2): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_packetout'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x1412): undefined reference to `ogg_page_bos'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x1424): undefined reference to `ogg_page_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x143d): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_pagein'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x1737): undefined reference to `ogg_page_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x1773): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_pagein'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x1a2c): undefined reference to `ogg_page_bos'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x1ab1): undefined reference to `ogg_page_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x1b0b): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_reset_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x26e0): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x2731): undefined reference to `ogg_page_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x27e4): undefined reference to `ogg_page_granulepos'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x2997): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x29b3): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x2a9e): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x2b08): undefined reference to `ogg_page_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x2b38): undefined reference to `ogg_page_granulepos'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x2eaa): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x31c1): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3304): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_clear'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x330e): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_clear'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3414): undefined reference to `ogg_page_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3420): undefined reference to `ogg_page_granulepos'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x37b1): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x37bb): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_buffer'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x37e9): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_wrote'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x37fb): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3807): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_pageout'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3819): undefined reference to `ogg_page_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3823): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_reset_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x382e): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_pagein'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3839): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_packetout'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3854): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_clear'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x385c): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_clear'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3a34): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3ab3): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3b7c): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_buffer'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x3b96): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_wrote'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4595): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x49d6): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4a8b): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4ad6): undefined reference to `ogg_page_serialno'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4ae7): undefined reference to `ogg_page_packets'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4af7): undefined reference to `ogg_page_granulepos'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfilC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4ca3): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_pagein'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4de7): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfilC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4e72): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_pagein'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4e82): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_packetout'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4ea0): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x4f30): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x53e6): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_pagein'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x5407): undefined reference to `ogg_stream_packetout'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0x562d): undefined reference to `ogg_sync_reset'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../lib\libopusfile.a(opusfile.o):(.text+0xc7f): undefined reference to `opus_multistream_decoder_ctl'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

i was expecting the program to compile normally

